# Changing default GCC Compiler in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, gcc, update-alternatives

I just downgraded from 13.04, which seems to have some stability problems right now, and moved back to 12.04.LTS.

I installed the GCC 4.8 compiler, which is not the default GCC compiler on 12.04. I need this compiler to get all the C++ 11 features it supports and were there by default with the compiler that comes with 13.04, using the ‘-std=c++11' switch.

So now I have 4.8 compiler installed, but I can't figure out how to make applications understand that the new compiler should be used for gcc/g++ instead of the default GCC compiler that comes with 12.04 (4.4.x?). How do I do this?

I saw somewhere that `update-alternatives` would do it. But I don't know to how use it to set the new GCC compiler to be the system default.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907026/pointing-codelite-to-new-compiler-gcc-4-8-x for the required commands to upgrade to 4.8.